# How to use Multi-Level/Nested in Ajax Calls?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am making a small intuitive web application with multi-level options which loads without refreshing the whole page.

My structure goes like:

```
/index.php
/schools.html
/colleges.html
```

[image]

Where schools.html will contain the full content of schools divided into div id sections. And same with colleges.html.

After clicking the schools menu in left table, It should schools.html class with options  like "Search by State".. and clicking the "Search by State".

I have tried all the possible baked options available, freeajaxcodes.blogspot.in/2009/05/7-ways-to-load-content-via-ajax.html

I'm still confused if this is the efficient way of what i want to accomplish. I want to concentrate on CSS and want to make this app as light as possible.

Comment: you should concentrate more on making it "work" than thinking about "efficiency". premature optimization is the root of all evil. I suggest creating the UI first, with parts "as if the AJAX content was loaded", then worry about how the AJAX will do its job, *then* you can worry about efficiency.

Comment: @Joseph I agree without point of "premature optimization" is evil. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to transmit only data on my ajax call (with json format). It is the client (with javascript/jQuery and CSS) which update the page with a good MVC (Model View Controller) architecture.